# MRTK3 - Touch Events Problems

Tags: augmented-reality, virtual-reality, mrtk

**Situation:** I am currently having a control panel (including some buttons, etc.) on a Canvas GameObject.

**Goal:** My goal is that the canvas is only visible if the user looks at the control panel (eye gaze hover).

**Problem:** For this, I added the "Stateful Interactable" component (MRTK3) to the Canvas GameObject. This component allows to define certain actions depending on events (in my case: “Is Gaze Hovered"). This works in general, i.e. the control panel is set to visible/invisible depending on the eye gaze hover. However - and this is the problem - if I add the "Stateful Interactable" component to the Canvas GameObject, the child Game Objects (e.g. the buttons) are not clickable any more. I already tried a lot of things to solve the problem (I assume that the Stateful Interactable Component intercepts the touch events but does not forward them to the child Game Objects).

Can anyone help out?